# Define 2 separate variables in Dictionary list with for each loop

Tags: c#, arraylist

This my code so far, I'm having trouble defining the string and UInt32 selected from list array inside the for each loop. Could anyone tell me how to over come this problem?

```
 Dictionary<string, UInt32> cars = new Dictionary<string, UInt32>();

 cars.Add("Vehicle1", 4294967295);
 cars.Add("Vehicle2", 6329496762);

 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, UInt32> pair in cars)
 {
     string vehiclename = pair.Item1; 
     UInt32 vehicledata = pair.Item2;   
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax is

```
 // You have to switch to long from UInt32 since... 
 Dictionary<string, long> cars = new Dictionary<string, long>();

 cars.Add("Vehicle1", 4294967295L);
 cars.Add("Vehicle2", 6329496762L); // ... this value is greater than UInt32.MaxValue

 // var: you have no need to put such a long declaration as KeyValuePair<string, long>
 foreach (var pair in cars)
 {
     string vehiclename = pair.Key; 
     long vehicledata = pair.Value;   
 }
```

please, notice that `KeyValuePair<string, long>` unlike `Tuple<string, long>` has `Key` and `Value` properties

Comment: Additionally, `6329496762` is greater than `uint.MaxValue`.

Comment: @Quantic: Nice catch! Thank you!

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you